Change in classwise distribution of hidden layer outputs given categorical crossentropy loss in a single layer linear neural network
Given a linear neural net with a single hidden layer, and a set of input samples $\mathbf X\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. Consider an input $\mathbf x\in \mathbf X$, such that output
$$\mathbf z=\mathbf{Wx}\\
\mathbf y'=\mathbf{Fz}$$
Where $\mathbf W\in\mathbb R^{d\times m}$ are the hidden layer weights that can be adjusted. $\mathbf F\in\mathbb R^{c\times d};c<d, \mathbf F\mathbf F^\top=\mathbf I$ remains fixed during optimization.
The output of the network is trained on a classification task using categorical cross-entropy loss using $\mathbf y'$ as softmax logits. My aim is to understand the dynamics of how the distribution of $\mathbf z$ evolves in this case.
It is clear that it must depend on the distribution of $\mathbf x$ and the weights. However, intuition suggests that whatever the distribution of $\mathbf x$ might be, as the weights evolve during training, they must pull the instances of same class closer and push instances of different classes away from each other due to the nature of the cross-entropy loss. Thus,

Can we mathematically show that interclass covariance (covariance between class means) increases and intraclass covariance (covariance between samples belonging to the same class) decreases at $\mathbf z$ compared to $\mathbf x$?
Can we do so without making any assumptions on the distribution of $\mathbf x$ or $\mathbf z$? What assumptions must we make?


My attempt:
For a given $\mathbf x\in \mathbf X$, the gradient is:
$$\nabla\mathbf W=\mathbf F^\top(\mathbf s-\mathbf y)\mathbf x^\top$$
where $\mathbf s=\mathrm{softmax}(\mathbf y')$ and $\mathbf y$ is a one-hot vector corresponding to classification target. Notably here, everything except $\mathbf s$ is fixed for a given $\mathbf x,\mathbf y$ pair.
Let $\mathbf{\tilde z}$ be some vector such that $\mathbf{F\tilde z}=\mathbf e$, where $\mathbf e$ is a vector of all ones. Then $\mathbf s$ turns out to be uniform and we get a boundary case. The other extreme is when $\mathbf z=\mathbf F^\top\mathbf y$, we have a zero gradient.
Using this, I can imagine that all points would be pushed away from some fixed $\mathbf{\tilde z}$ and towards respective orthogonal row vectors in $\mathbf F$. I am not sure if this is useful to show what I need.
